# После текста вью остаётся пустое пространство на полстраницы

Tags: xcode, objective-c, autolayout, textview, прокрутка

Есть вьюха главная (`MainView`), на ней скролл вью (`scrollView`), на ней опять вью (`contentView`), и вот в этой вью имеется `ImageView`, под ней `TextView`(размер текста меняется в зависимости от выбранной ячейки таблицы).

В Detail.m прописал:

```
 CGRect frameTextView = _textView.frame;
//установка высоты TextView равной размеру его содержимого
frameTextView.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frameTextView;
self.textView.frame = frameTextView;

CGRect contentViewFrame = _ContentView.frame;

contentViewFrame.size.height += _textView.contentSize.height ;//- _textView.frame.size.height; если убрать // то не будет скроллить, скролл будет но скроллится не будет то есть вниз идти или вверх

_ContentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
_scrollView.contentSize = _ContentView.frame.size;
_ContentView.frame = _scrollView.frame;
```

И вот после всего этого в приложении остаётся пустое место после `textView`, нехорошо. Как убрать пустоту? Ах, да, авто лаяут включен. Благодарю.

Comment: Всё, вопрос решён.
Минусанул фрайм от ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Если что, вот код, который дает высоту текстового содержимого:

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText: (NSAttributedString*)text andWidth: (CGFloat)width {

    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, 9999.0)];

    return size.height;
}
```